# TestNg Script failure inside my servlet. WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port within 45000 ms

Tags: java, servlets, testng

**Code to execute my testng xml from inside servlet:**

```java
TestListenerAdapter adp = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
List<String> suites = new ArrayList<String>();
suites.add("D:\\testng.xml"); 
tng.setTestSuites(suites);
tng.run();
```

**Error Message after running above through servlet method:**

```
[TestNG] Running:
  D:\\testng.xml


===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

Below is the sample test script class file using in xml file

```
package simpleTestng;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNgSample {

        WebDriver d;
        @BeforeClass
        public void test_open_browser(){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://Selenium//driver//firefoxdriver//firefoxdriver.exe");
            d=new FirefoxDriver();  

        }

        @Test
        public void open_page(){
            d.get("https://www.google.com");
            String  title=d.getTitle();
            System.out.println("title is "+title);  
        }

        @AfterClass
        public void test_close_browser(){
        d.quit();
        }
    }
```

I am getting following web-driver Exception ,if right click on class file and run as Testng test

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:121)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:77)
    at simpleTestng.TestNgSample.test_open_browser(TestNgSample.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:51)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:85)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1197)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1122)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)
```

Comment: This question lacks a lot of information. Have you looked at either the stacktrace (or) the test reports that are generated to see what is the problem ? You can have TestNG atleast temporarily dump the test results by setting `tng.setUseDefaultListeners(true)`. Your test results seem to suggest that you have test failures.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I added complete  test scripts here, can you please check This once ...Thanks